# Which components are adding emotion css global styles

Tags: javascript, css, gatsby, emotion, grommet

Two global syles entries are added to my pages and I cannot have control over them.

Could you help me to understand which components are injecting them?

App developed in gatsby using:
Grommet
Styled components

Code gets included in header section

```html
<style data-emotion="css-global"> ... <style>
<style data-emotion="css-global"> ... <style>
```

I would like to know, how I can debug the issue? Let's say which component is responsible for adding these two lines.

Answer (score -1):

These are defined in Emotion's `<Global />` component ([emotion global styles](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals)). If you used a starter or theme this is probably the source. If this isn't enough direction, please share a link to the starter or theme repo, or to your repo.